# Scheduled Task SQL timeout, but not when running manually

Tags: sql, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a problem where I have to run a C# Console application via a scheduled task.  The scheduled task calls a Powershell script which sets some variables (like a connection string) and calls a C# console application which connects to a database with those arguments.

The problem is that when the scheduled task is triggered by the time trigger, I see from the logs the application starting as normal, trying to execute a query, but failing with a SQl timeout.

Manually running the application from the Scheduled Task Window (right-click>Run) works fine, even seconds after it failed when running automatically. This behaviour is so consistent (triggered failed, manual runs) that I don't think it's the database.

It's also not the startup directory, user rights or differences in the arguments, the application is starting, it's just failing at database access.

What can be the cause of this behaviour and how do I remedy it?

Some settings of the task:

- Run with highest privileges: ON
- Run whether the user is logged in or not
- Do not store password: OFF
- User account is the same as the logged in user
- Trigger not stopped when running to long
- Startup directory and script location correct (application is starting and logging, just failing at database access. Manual Right-click>Run works always)

Stack trace of the error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TrySetMetaData(_SqlMetaDataSet metaData, Boolean moreInfo)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does your connection string look like? Consider testing using the IP address of the server (if you're not already doing so).

Comment: We are using CNAME records, so not the actual IP in the connection string. I can ping the server name I put in the connection string as normal, and it responds as normal. The conneciton string looks like: Server=DBSERVER-NAME;database=databaseName;uid=username;pwd=password;PersistSecurityInfo=True; But it is (should be?) using the same connection string running manually as triggered, so what effect could that have? but I'll try the actual IP address next

Comment: what does your code look like? there is a SQL module for PowerShell (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer) - there the command `Invoke-SqlCmd` has a Parameter `QueryTimeout`.

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz, Thanks, I know. The application I already have, and it does a lot more than just querying a database or executing some SQL. Powershell is just used as the driver to start the application with the correct arguments (one of the arguments is a flexible date that Powershell calculates and feeds to the console application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure I remember having the same issue with timeout occurring while trying to get table META data.

I may well be very wrong here, but if I do remember correctly, this was down to the failure of the column type detection by trying to parse a date in the wrong (or unexpected format). I have a vague recollection of this having to do with mismatch between the operating system Regional Settings, current user regional settings and the SQL Server Language setting.

Should your query return any date fields?

I think this was resolved by ensuring that as soon as the database was connected, the following query was executed to force the DB connection to use dates is ISO format:

```
        using (SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("SET DATEFORMAT YMD", _conn))
        {
            sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

It would follow that when you run the task interactively, it will connect to the database and the format will be in your active regional setting, however when run automatically by via Scheduled Tasks, it only impersonates your user but does not carry the associated regional settings, it uses those of the OS instead.

Comment: That looks like a possibility and would explain the difference in manual/automatic tasks. Indeed the application queries a database and it returns date fields. The table is in an old legacy database, so unexpected formats are a definite possiblity. I'll try this out in the next days and report back

Comment: Was able to do a new release today with your changes in there, and it seems to be working! What an obscure issue, but thanks for the help!

Comment: @CerylWiltink How do you think you had unexpected formats in your legacy database? Is there a way to identify them? I have the similar issue but I am not sure if I have any invalid format in my `datetime` fields in SQL Server. I run this query `select dateformat from sys.syslanguages where name = @@LANGUAGE` and I get `mdy`. Should I set it to `YMD` like in the answer? Can you share your ideas?

Comment: @Fer It has been quite some time since this issue, so I'm afraid I cannot remember too many details. I also switched jobs in the meantime so I cannot check back on this anymore. Digging into my memory; while this answer seemed a solution, I think it actually turned out to be a Domain Controller problem unrelated to the database. I guess it might be worth trying this to see if helps. But a better step might be to open a new question on StackOverflow with a full description of your problem, it might get better answers. Good luck!

Comment: @CerylWiltink thank you very much. I will analyze more on my issue and open a new question if I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has an accepted answer; however, to add a bit of flavour, this issue can easily be solved by setting the task scheduler properly.

If your OS is Win10 then on `Task Scheduler --> General Tab --> Configure for -->` select "Windows 10".

In most cases will easily solve the issue.